# MapInfo TAB - Integer fields and null values

Tags: mapinfo

Can MapInfo TAB integer fields hold null values?

Is there a spec document on MapInfo TAB attributes available for download?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the tab file format doesn't support NULL values.
If you need NULL values you need to define your own NULL values, for instance -9999.

Comment: Ha-ha, you dont know how many issues this has given my clients in the past!